# Eclipselink: persistence.xml connect to derby glassfish localhost database (create and populate database)

Tags: java, xml, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I need to connect to a localhost derby database (in glassfish 4) with eclipselink.
I want to generate the database from the classes or a sql script. 
In the persistence.xml file I have :

```
  <persistence-unit name="chapter04PU" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
     <class>org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter04.Book</class>
     <properties>
     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="chapter04Create.ddl"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="chapter04Drop.ddl"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter04DB;create=true"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="insert.sql"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
     </properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work. the above persistence unit was correct.
Assuming that the in an Entity Book class the id has the following annotations:
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;

With the following persistence unit:

```
   <persistence-unit name="Book"  transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
     <class>com.tutorial.Book</class>
      <properties>
       <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="create.ddl"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="drop.ddl"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/library_db;create=true"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="insert.sql"/>
       <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
   </properties>
```

Scripts like the following:

**create.ddl** ------------------------------------------------------------

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255),
    ILLUSTRATIONS SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
    ISBN VARCHAR(255),
    NBOFPAGE INTEGER,
    PRICE FLOAT,
    TITLE VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID))

CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (
    SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(15),
    PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))

INSERT INTO SEQUENCE(SEQ_NAME, SEQ_COUNT) values ('SEQ_GEN', 0)
```

**drop.ddl** --------------------------------------------------

```
DROP TABLE book

DELETE FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'SEQ_GEN'
```

**insert.sql**----------------------------------------

```
INSERT INTO BOOK(ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ILLUSTRATIONS, ISBN, NBOFPAGE, PRICE)
values (1000, 'Beginning Java EE 6', 'Best Java EE book ever', 1, '1234-5678', 450, 49)

INSERT INTO BOOK(ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ILLUSTRATIONS, ISBN, NBOFPAGE, PRICE)
values (1001, 'Beginning Java EE 7', 'No, this is the best ', 1, '5678-9012', 550, 53)
```